# Skia Sharp DrawText not considering Android accessibility settings (Font Size)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp, skia

If user changes the Font Size from default to large or largest in androids accessibility settings all labels are scaled up. But drawing text with DrawText method on a canvas has no effect.

Is this the expected behaviour? I thought that text which was drawn with skia sharp also scales up.
What is the correct way to work with android accessibility changes in skia sharp?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, this expected.  Skia does not use native Android text APIs to draw text.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to find the scaling is via a deprecated Android API:

```cs
// First, test this in YourApp.Android project's MainActivity.cs.

// Returns "1" at default scale. Larger value when font should be larger.
public float CurrentFontScale()
{
    Android.Util.DisplayMetrics metrics = new Android.Util.DisplayMetrics();
    // Deprecated. But if it compiles, it works.
    WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
    float scaledDensity = metrics.ScaledDensity;
    return scaledDensity;
}

// Call it from here:
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle){
{
    ...
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    float fontScale = CurrentFontScale();

    ...
}
```

MULTIPLY all Skia font sizes by this.

After confirming the code works in `MainActivity.cs`,
to use this in a cross-platform Xamarin project, create a [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction). How to do that is beyond scope of this answer.

---

As a practical matter, consider "limiting" how large a given font size grows. Otherwise, layout becomes difficult.
E.g. `myFontSize = Math.Min(20 * fontScale, 48);` for a text string that would be too large at fontsize greater than 48.

An alternative is to use `SKPaint.MeasureText(somestring)`, after creating an skpaint with desired font size, and limit the fontSize if text gets too long:

```cs
// --- Auto-fit Skia text. ---
// These are typically parameters.
string somestring = "Hello, World";
float MaxAllowedWidth = 100;   // Pixels.
float fontSize = 20 * fontScale;

SKFont font = new SKFont(typeface, fontSize);
SKPaint textPaint = new SKPaint(font);
float textWidth = textPaint.MeasureText(somestring);
if (textWidth > MaxAllowedWidth)
{
    // --- Shrink as needed. ---
    // "Floor" to avoid being slightly too wide sometimes.
    fontSize = Math.Floor(fontSize * MaxAllowedWidth / textWidth);
    font = new SKFont(typeface, fontSize);
    textPaint = new SKPaint(font);

    // OPTIONAL VERIFY: This should now be less than MaxAllowedWidth.
    textWidth = textPaint.MeasureText(somestring);
}

... paint the text ...
```